# Custom function not implementing

Tags: p5.js

I tried making my own function to have a heart draw animation in the specific coordinates I choose, but for some reason when I try implement it, it isn't showing up on the canvas. I know I have done something VERY wrong somewhere but cannot wrap my head around it.

```
let points = [];
let a = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(928,500);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  heart(200, 200, 10);
}

function heart(x, y, r) {
  r = r;
  x = x + (r * 16 * pow(sin(a), 3));
  y = y + (-r * (13 * cos(a) - 5 * cos(2 * a) - 2 * cos(3 * a) - cos(4 * a)));
  
  beginShape();
  points.forEach(point => {
    vertex(point.x, point.y);
  })
  endShape();

  points.push(x, y);
  a += 0.05
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind for a self draw?

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(928,500);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  heart(200, 200, 10, frameCount / 200); //the last value is how much of the heart is made, you can change by how much it is divided to alter the speed
}

function heart(X, Y, r, limit) {
translate(X,Y);


beginShape();
for(a = 0; a < limit; a += 0.01){
    let x = (r * 16 * pow(sin(a), 3));
let y = (-r * (13 * cos(a) - 5 * cos(2 * a) - 2 * cos(3 * a) - cos(4 * a)));
    vertex(x,y);
}
endShape();}
```

Comment: If anything else comes up don't be afraid to ask, it's my first time helping someone.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed, it's really nice, well done. I don't know the limit of 'a' though so I might be looping for no reason.

```js
    function heart(X, Y, r) {
    translate(X,Y);
  
    
    beginShape();
    for(a = 0; a < 10; a += 0.05){
        let x = (r * 16 * pow(sin(a), 3));
    let y = (-r * (13 * cos(a) - 5 * cos(2 * a) - 2 * cos(3 * a) - cos(4 * a)));
        vertex(x,y);
    }
    endShape();}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling to understand my own work and yours has cleared it up. I was actually looking for the heart to draw itself though as a little animation, is there anyway of making that happen with the above code?